# Add a web hook button to an email

Tags: zapier

Hey guys I use Zapier to pull row data from Google sheets and then use those values to send an email.

I want to give the recipient a way to click a button and this could change a cell in a Google sheet(I would use zapier to achive this)

My idea is to use a web hook to post the data to my zapier URL and then use this as a trigger.

Does anyone know how to embed a button in an email that allows this

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That sort of thing is technically possible, but it will look weird to your end user. When you set up your "Catch Hook" Webhook trigger, it will provide you a url. You can put this into any email (or clickable location) and it will trigger the zap whenever it's clicked. You'll need to make sure you put parameters on it so there's data to pass into the zap. For instance:

https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/12345/abcd?name=Rob

When it's clicked, the user will the raw json response and the zap will be passed the following input:

```
{
  "name": "Rob"
}
```

for use in other steps.

Hope this helps!